# Get receipt information of renewable in app product purchase in ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How to get latest receipt information of a renewable in app product in ios and how to check whether receipt is expire or not?
My code is : 
- For getting receipt

```
            -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions
            {
                hide_HUD
                SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = transactions.lastObject;
                switch (transaction.transactionState) {
                    case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    {
                        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                        NSLog(@"Order id ======>> %@",transaction.transactionIdentifier);
                        NSData *recData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
                        NSString* receiptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:recData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                        [self getReceiptFromAppStore:recData Transaction:transaction isBackground:NO];
                        break;
                    }

                    case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                        NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                        break;

                    case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                        break;

                    default:
                        //NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

- For getting receipt

  ```
      -(void)getReceiptFromAppStore:(NSData*)ReceiptData Transaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*)AutoTransaction isBackground:(BOOL)isBackground
      {
          NSData *receipt=ReceiptData; // Sent to the server by the device

          // Create the JSON object that describes the request
          NSError *error;
          NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                            @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0],
                                            @"password" : @“*********************”
                                            };
          NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:&error];

          if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }

          // Create a POST request with the receipt data.
          NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; //for Testing
          //    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];//for live
          NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
          [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
          [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

          // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
          NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
          [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                                 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                                     if (connectionError) {

                                     } else {
                                         NSError *error;
                                         NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                                         if (error == nil && [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"] != nil && [[jsonResponse valueForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"] count] > 0) {
                                            /* 
                                           What I have to do here to check receipt is expire.  
                                           My goal is to user can not redirect to my   
                                           app’s home page if he unsubscribe.  
                                           For example if user purchased 1 month . 
                                           renewable plan on 20-1-2017 and on 25-1-2017
                                           he/she unsubscribe for that plan and after 1 month (on 22-2-2017),  
                                           if he/she open my app , he should not get   
                                           redirected to my app’s home page.
                                           */
                                         }
                                         else{
                                             NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }];
      }
  ```

I have got receipt but I don't know how to get data from receipt and how to use it for preventing user to go to app's home page.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  There is a lot of information available from Apple as well as other questions here and other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly read about receipt fields, You will have a all information like expire, cancelled by apple, billing info, cancellation and so on..

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12)

You have to access latest object from **latest_receipt_info** array and check for field **expires_date**

The expiration date for the subscription, expressed as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

ASN.1 Field Type 1708

ASN.1 Field Value IA5STRING, interpreted as an RFC 3339 date

JSON Field Name expires_date

JSON Field Value string, interpreted as an RFC 3339 date

This key is only present for auto-renewable subscription receipts. Use this value to identify the date when the subscription will renew or expire, to determine if a customer should have access to content or service. After validating the latest receipt, if the subscription expiration date for the latest renewal transaction is a past date, it is safe to assume that the subscription has expired.

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan